# How HTML React only Unescape some code

Tags: html, reactjs, escaping, unescapestring

I have a some code

```
let red = 'red'
let blue = 'blue'
let formula = "1+2"
let answer = "3"
let string = "<span class="+red+">"+formula+"</span>"+"="+"<span class="+blue+">"+answer+"</span>"
```

111
In render's return

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: string]}} >
```

the above will show "1+23" with no color, however, I want 1+2=3 with red and blue classes created

UPDATE: I found should not be "className", should be "class" even this is in jsx, I still cannot get the equal being shown, in fact the class is from a string also

Comment: I think syntax are not correct. use this 
`let string = '<span className="red">'+formula+'</span>=<span className="blue">'+answer+'</span>'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the quotes in you HTML string, enclose the `classes` within single quotes like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let formula = "1+2"
        let answer = "3"
        let string = "<span className='red'>"+formula+"</span>"+"="+"<span className='blue'>"+answer+"</span>"
        return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: string}} ></div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```